# Google site kit Interrupted: As you did not grant the necessary permissions

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I did make my own WordPress site and want to install the Google site kit plugin to see the analytics. When following the steps there is an error:
*"The Site Kit setup was interrupted because you did not grant the necessary permissions. To fix this, redo the plugin setup."*
I tried multiple times and search on the internet. On internet I saw people getting a popup screen to allow permission, but I didn't see this pop-up. I tried to de-active all my plugins, re-installed google site kit. Nothing is working.
Please help!

Comment: I tried with my other (personal) account and get the permission pop-up right away. So i think it has something to do with my account?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to ensure all the required permissions are granted!

[image: Permissions required]